# What is the shortest way of getting the last N items of an array?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I wrote

```
array = linspace(0, 1);
sliceSize = 10;
sliceBegin = 1 + length(array) - sliceSize;
slice = array(sliceBegin: length(array));
```

that's too verbose. How to make it shorter?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
a = rand(100,1);    %# vector
a(end-5+1:end)      %# last five elements
```